# i have a route path where id can be optional how to specify it in routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
 <Container>
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen/>} exact/>
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen/>}/>
          <Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen/>} />
          </Routes>
 </Container>
```

in the above code for cart screen id parameter is optional it may or may not present so i placed a "?" after id

```
const addToCart = () => {
      navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)
 }
```

when i navigate to /cart/${id}?qty=${qty} i need to go to the CartScreen component how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be to to define two routes to the same component and then handle in the component weather the parameter exists or not. Like this:

```js
<Route path="/cart/:id" element={<CartScreen />} />
<Route path="/cart/" element={<CartScreen />} />
```

Though on [this post from atomized objects](https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/quick-fixes/how-to-use-react-router-with-an-optional-path-parameter/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20in%20an%20optional,signify%20that%20it%20is%20optional.&text=And%20then%20in%20your%20component,passed%20in%20by%20React%20Router.) they show this other alternative but not sure if it's compatible with `react router v6`:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={CartScreen} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```